# Как вывести данные из БД помощью дискорд бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Данной командой пользователь может сохранить данные о себе в БД.

```
@slash.subcommand(base='note', name='add', description='Adds a user id with a note to the database.', guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def add(ctx, user_id: str, user_name: str, note: str, friend_code: str, sex: str):
    database = sqlite3.connect('user_notes.db')
    c = database.cursor()
    c.execute(f"INSERT INTO user_notes VALUES ('{user_id}', '{user_name}', '{note}', '{friend_code}', '{sex}')")
    database.commit()
    database.close()
    await ctx.send('User and note successfully added!', hidden=True)
```

как сделать команду, которая будет выводить данные пользователя по его ID?

Например

> /note show @user1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('user_notes.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_notes (
    user_id INT,
    user_name TEXT,
    note TEXT,
    friend_code INT,
    sex TEXT
)""")
for guild in self.client.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
        if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM user_notes WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{user_id}', '{user_name}', '{note}', '{friend_code}', '{sex}')")
            connection.commit()
        else:
            pass
connection.commit()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Может ты создашь отдельную функцию сохранения пользователя в бд?
Например, когда чел заходит в дискорд-гильдию, бот тут же добавляет его в бд.
Это проще будет, ибо каждый раз чел должен писать

> /note show @user1

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос